# Mule transformation best practice

Tags: mule

I am building a REST API in Mule that on the backend orchestrates multiple SOAP web services to get the needed data to return as JSON to requests to the REST API.

I convert my SOAP responses to DTO's using JAXB and then map the JAXB DTO's to a set of Jackson DTO's for serialising as JSON using a scripting transformer to map one structure to the other. Sort of like a anti-corruption layer to map the one context to the other.

However I have been reading about using a Canonical Data Model to loosely couple the different data structures.

Is this a valid use case for using a Canonical Data Model?

Is this extra layer of any benefit? The way I see it, if the backend SOAP services change, I still need to change just one transformer.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The canonical data model is used when you need common data types to be used by different apps or flows.  The focus is reusability of the app or flow.

Since you are encapsulating SOAP services, you don't need to create a CDM for the back-end SOAP services if they are mutually exclusive point-to-point calls and not aggregated responses from your Mule flow's perspective.

You can use a CDM internally in your app if the criteria below is true.

- You perform the same processing on the data from multiple SOAP web service calls.
- The data format from each SOAP web service call is different.
- The different data formats are transformable into a CDM

In that case you would transform the data from each SOAP call into a CDM and then use the common processing flow and then send response back to REST caller.

General best practice is to convert data right after inbound endpoint to a common format for processing and then converting it to specific format right before outbound endpoint.  These are applied when you have multiple inbound or multiple outbound endpoints in app.